# How to generate the permutation notation isomorphic generator of a group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am looking for a technique or algorithm to find generators in permutation notation for the isomorphic group. In other words, I'd like an approach for finding the subgroups of a symmetric group that are isomorphic to the given group (per Cayley's theorem).

For example, finding $(1\space2)$ for addition in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, or finding $(1\space2\space3\space4)$ and $(5\space 6)$ if given the symmetry group of the square.

These are simple examples, but I am looking for a systematic way to construct such generators.

My ultimate objective is to find generators in cyclic permutation notation for all groups of order $n$.

Any references or relevant associated topics would be appreciated.

Comment: You are basically asking to find all faithful actions of a group on a given set. I'm not sure there is something particularly efficient for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the generators of the previous group are known, you can put all the elements of a group in a list (some other people call this a [Cayley Embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866026/quaternion-group-as-permutation-group)), perform the group operation on each element of the list using the generator, and see how the order of the list changes. This gives the isomorphic generator as a permutation.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, I'd like an approach for finding the subgroups of a symmetric group that are isomorphic to the given group (per Cayley's theorem).

For any given group $G$ of order $n$, the routine you are looking for is represented by the composition:
$$G\stackrel{\epsilon}{\hookrightarrow} S_G\stackrel{\varphi^{(f)}}{\to} S_n$$
where $\epsilon$ is Cayley's embedding and $\varphi^{(f)}$ is the isomorphism defined by $\alpha\mapsto f\alpha f^{-1}$, being $f\colon G\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ *any* bijection. For example, take $G=(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z,+)=$ $\{[0],[1],[2],[3]\}$ and $f$ the bijection defined by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
[0]\mapsto 1 \\
[1]\mapsto 2 \\
[2]\mapsto 3 \\
[3]\mapsto 4 \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
What is the *permutation* (=element of $S_4$) corresponding to, for instance, $[2]$? To answer, we need to let the "left multiplication" (well, "addition" in this case) by $[2]$ to act, and see how our (arbitrary) choice $(1)$ *realizes* it as an element of $S_4$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
(f([2]+\_)f^{-1})(1) &= f([2]+[0]) &&= f([2]) &&&= 3 \\
(f([2]+\_)f^{-1})(2) &= f([2]+[1]) &&= f([3]) &&&= 4 \\
(f([2]+\_)f^{-1})(3) &= f([2]+[2]) &&= f([0]) &&&= 1 \\
(f([2]+\_)f^{-1})(4) &= f([2]+[3]) &&= f([1]) &&&= 2 \\
\tag2
\end{alignat}
and hence:
$$[2]\stackrel{\varphi^{(f)}\epsilon}{\longmapsto} (13)(24)$$
Likewise, still with the same (arbitrary) choice $(1)$, we get:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&[0]\stackrel{\varphi^{(f)}\epsilon}{\longmapsto} (1)(2)(3)(4)=() \\
&[1]\stackrel{\varphi^{(f)}\epsilon}{\longmapsto} (1234) \\
&[3]\stackrel{\varphi^{(f)}\epsilon}{\longmapsto} (1432) \\
\end{alignat}
Collectively:
$$\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\stackrel{\varphi^{(f)}\epsilon}{\cong}H_1:=\{(),(1234),(13)(24),(1432)\}$$
The other two copies of $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ in $S_4$, say $H_2$ and $H_3$, pop up by trying different bijections $f$ than the one in $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a given labelling $G=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$, the left multiplication by a given $a_i\in G$ defines implicitly the permutation $\sigma_i\in S_n$ via:
$$a_ia_j=:a_{\sigma_i(j)} \tag1$$
**Claim**. $\Sigma:=\{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n\}\cong G$.

*Proof*. Firstly, we have to prove that $\Sigma\le S_n$. From $(1)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
a_{(\sigma_i\sigma_j)(k)} &= a_{\sigma_i(\sigma_j(k))} \\
&\stackrel{}{=} a_ia_{\sigma_j(k)}\\
&\stackrel{}{=} a_i(a_ja_k) \\
&= (a_ia_j)a_k \\
&\stackrel{}{=} a_{\sigma_i(j)}a_k \\
&\stackrel{}{=} a_{\sigma_{\sigma_i(j)}(k)} \\
\tag2
\end{alignat}
Since $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are pairwise distict by assumption, from $(2)$ it follows:
$$\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_{\sigma_i(j)}\in\Sigma\tag3$$
whence the closure of $\Sigma$ and the desired result.

Now consider the map $\varphi\colon a_i\mapsto\sigma_i$. The injectivity (and hence the bijectivity) follows from $a_i$'s being pairwise distinct, whereas operation-preserving follows from $(1)$ and $(3)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi(a_ia_j) &= \varphi(a_{\sigma_i(j)}) \\
&= \sigma_{\sigma_i(j)} \\
&= \sigma_i\sigma_j \\
&= \varphi(a_i)\varphi(a_j) \\
\end{alignat}
$\Box$

As in other answer of mine, to get concrete $\sigma_i$'s you have to make some original choice about the labelling of $G$'s elements. For example, yet again with $G=(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z,+)$, the identification:
\begin{alignat}{1}
a_1=[0] \\
a_2=[1] \\
a_3=[2] \\
a_4=[3] \\
\end{alignat}
brings us to:
\begin{alignat}{1}
a_{\sigma_1(1)} &= a_1a_1 &&= [0]+[0]=[0] &&&= a_1 \\
a_{\sigma_1(2)} &= a_1a_2 &&= [0]+[1]=[1] &&&= a_2 \\
a_{\sigma_1(3)} &= a_1a_3 &&= [0]+[2]=[2] &&&= a_3  \\
a_{\sigma_1(4)} &= a_1a_4 &&= [0]+[3]=[3] &&&= a_4 \\
\end{alignat}
namely $[0]\mapsto\sigma_1=()$. Likewise:
\begin{alignat}{1}
a_{\sigma_2(1)} &= a_2a_1 &&= [1]+[0]=[1] &&&= a_2 \\
a_{\sigma_2(2)} &= a_2a_2 &&= [1]+[1]=[2] &&&= a_3 \\
a_{\sigma_2(3)} &= a_2a_3 &&= [1]+[2]=[3] &&&= a_4  \\
a_{\sigma_2(4)} &= a_2a_4 &&= [1]+[3]=[0] &&&= a_1 \\
\end{alignat}
namely $[1]\mapsto\sigma_2=(1234)$. Etc.